# manage.py collectstatic: error: unrecognized arguments: --noinput in shell script launched by Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm working to launch a django-tornado hybrid app in a Docker container from a shell script and and getting `--noinput` as an unrecognized argument for django commands:

```
usage: manage.py collectstatic [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                               [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                               [--traceback] [--no-color] [--noinput]
                               [--no-post-process] [-i PATTERN] [-n] [-c] [-l]
                               [--no-default-ignore]
manage.py collectstatic: error: unrecognized arguments: --noinput
```

Why would I be getting `--noinput` as an unrecognized argument? My Dockerfile calls a deployment shell script which performs the `collectstatic` and `migrate` commands (both with the `--noinput` argument, which is failing for both. I've played around with removing extraneous lines, adjusting whitespace around the command, etc, to no avail. I can run the shell script locally without any issues; it seems to only be a problem in the Docker container `RUN` call to the shell script.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev

RUN mkdir /code
ADD . /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["sh","./deploy.sh"]

EXPOSE 8888
```

deploy.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py migrate --noinput
python main.py
```

If I run the django commands in the Dockerfile with `RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` there is no issue, but I'm trying to get the application-specific commands in the `CMD` call, since I need to have database environment vars from Elastic Beanstalk for my deployment environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like my issue was line endings in the shell script. I think sh was feeding in `--noinput\R` into python, so it was presenting itself in the terminal as looking like `--noinput`, but really it was getting a `CR` character as well that it was matching against.

When I was locally testing, it was in the Docker Quickstart terminal (where it worked), and the Docker containers were always running in Ubuntu (where it was failing).

I've hit this way in the past before where different line endings in shell scripts that were written on Windows messed things up in a Linux environment, and I need to remember how important it is to set up line endings correctly in my editors...

Comment: Is there any way around it? I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Make sure your editor doesn't insert `CR` characters in for shell scripts. If your versioning software is configured correctly, it should make sure checking things in/out have the right line endings. I added to my `.gitattributes` file `* text=auto` and `*.sh text eol=lf`. That, on it's own doesn't fix things if your editor is still adding `CRLF` instead of just `LF`, though, which was my big problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will keep this in mind the next time

Comment: Had the same problem, line endings was the problem. My development environment is Windows and I deploy to Linux env. I am using Pycharm and [Configuring Line Separators](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html) helped me.

Comment: I edited the file in Sublime Text and [set line endings to Unix](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/is-there-any-way-to-convert-files-line-ending-on-saving/25456/2).

Answer (score 1):

I Solve this problem using notepad++

In your notepad++

```
Do Inspection
View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters
Look for CR LF line endings, rather than LF line endings!

Solving
Search > Replace (Ctrl+H)
Make sure Search Mode is set to Extended
Find \r\n and replace with \n
```

main problem in this case is there are CR aka carriage return in your sh file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is line separator in windows, by default it takes CRLF. So you need to change it to LF. It depends on which editor you are using you can change it to LF.
For visual studio code (Vscode)  press ctrl + shift + P to open search pallet and type "Change End of Line sequence" you will see option to select LF/CRLF the please select LF from that options (Try To be in same .sh file where you are getting issue)and save the file again.
[image]

Optionally you can select same option from right bottom of your VSCode to do same process

[image]

For other editors you can search and follow same process